# Custom constraint validation error doesn't display next to field in Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints

I am using FOSUserBundle in my Symfony2 project. I added 'birthday' field in User entity, because it is required in registration form. I also added a proper field (type=birthday) to the registration form. I have to check if age of a user is above 18. I prepared my own Constraint for this following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html). Everything works perfectly, but error message is attached to form not to field, and I want error message next to field. Instead I get it above the whole form. Every other error in form is displayed next to a proper field. Does anybody know how to force constraint to be attached to the field, not to the form?

EDIT:

Twig code fragment which renders this particular field:

```
<div class="grid_8" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
      <div class="grid_2 alpha">{{ form_label(form.date_of_birth)}}</div>
      <div class="grid_4">{{ form_widget(form.date_of_birth)}}</div>
      <div class="grid_2 omega">{{ form_errors(form.date_of_birth)}}</div>
</div>
```

At the begining of the form I also have:

```
<div class="grid_8">
  {{form_errors(form)}}
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share your twig code?

Answer (score 4):

If you attach callback to form – not to particular field, you should set property path a bit different way:

```php
public function isFormValid($data, ExecutionContext $context)
{
    if ( $condition == false ) {
        $context->addViolationAt('[date_of_birth].date_of_birth', 'You are too young!');
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Why [date_of_birth], not only the ID of field (i.e. date_of_birth) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the violation to one particular field with `addViolationAtSubPath()` instead of the classic `addViolation()` used in the validator. You can have a look at the method definition [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContext.php#L153-163).

### An example

Lets take the example of a validator that need to validate that the username property is alphanumeric:

```php
class ContainsAlphanumericValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Za0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->addViolationAtSubPath('username',$constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

You can also take a look at [addViolationAtPath()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContext.php#L120-137) and [addViolationAt()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContext.php#L168-183).