# Symfony 2 custom validator on field

Tags: validation, symfony, field, constraints

I made my custom date range validator, and I'm using it on date properties of my entity..

Though, **when I get an error it's attached to the form and not to the field**.
So I can't display errors with `{{form_errors(form.date)}}`. (edit : form is a prototype of a child collection)

I saw that : [Custom constraint validation error doesn't display next to field in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027491/custom-constraint-validation-error-doesnt-display-next-to-field-in-symfony2) . But I don't want to explicitly specify on which field name the error should be attached..

Maybe it's related to the fact that this error is in a collection of the main form (using his prototype) ?

I could also add that the error is attached to the main parent form (my validator is on a field, which is in a form, which is a collection of a form, which is an embedded form of the main form).

How can I do ?

EDIT : It might be related to that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907415/symfony2-data-prototype-error-bubbling

Comment: Did you, by any chance, set the `error_bubbling` to `true` in your field?

Comment: No, I did not set the `error_bubbling` parameter.
Though I just edited my original post to add some precisions !

Answer (score 0):

It is surely related to `error_bubbling`. It defaults to `true` if the form is compound, so you should set it to `false` value.

```
$builder
        ->add('field', 'collection', [
            'type' => new ChildFormType(),
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ]);
```

See [symfony doc page about error_bubbling](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling) for more details