# How to add a custom validation callback error to a specific form type field?

Tags: symfony

I'm performing validation on an entity property using a custom constraint, but my forms are using setters and getters that don't correspond directly to the validating field, but affect it.

What I want to do is hook the validation errors on to the form field that originally handled the invalid user input.

Here's a much simplified example of the validating property and the setter method that the form binds to:

```
/* @Assert\ValidFoo */ 
private $foo;

public function setFooBar( $baz ){
    $this->foo->bar = $baz;
}
```

In my Twig template I want to be able to display the error with:

```
{{ form_errors(form.foobar) }}
```

I can dump out any errors at the end of the form with `{{form_errors(form)}}` but that's no good for my purposes. How can I alias the validation error onto the specific form field I want?

---

Update:

I've tried using `addViolationAt` as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027491/custom-constraint-validation-error-doesnt-display-next-to-field-in-symfony2) but it's not working for me. Possibly because the property path doesn't really exist?

Comment: Why you not use a [Validation Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)?

Comment: My validation callback is in the class property validator. It works, but the form doesn't know how to re-map the errors onto its fields. Are you suggesting I execute a validator with a callback directly in my form handling or in my form Type object?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand clearly but if you can't add the error in you controller (or in your formHandler class) like this: `if (!callback) $form->get('yourField')->addError(new FormError('error message'));` you can map the error callback  directly to the field you want in your formType like this: `$resolver->setDefaults(array('error_mapping' => array('yourCallback' => 'fieldYouWant')));`

Comment: Yes! error_mapping was the key. Thanks. I'll accept your answer if you add one.

Comment: glad to be helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the error callback directly to the field you want in your `formType` like this:

`$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'error_mapping' => array(
        'yourCallback' => 'fieldYouWant'
        )
    )
);`