# Custom constraint validation sometimes display near field sometimes doesn't Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints, symfony2-easyadmin

I build a custom constraint validation in Symfony 2 which calls Doctrine :

```
if($prevu != 0) {
        $total = $prevu + $consomme;
        if($total > $charge) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message1)
                 ->setParameter('%string%', $prevu)
                 ->atPath('intervention.dureeP')
                 ->addViolation();
        }
        dump($this);    
    }elseif($realise != 0) {
        $total = $realise + $consomme;
        if($total > $charge) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message2)
                 ->setParameter('%string%', $realise)
                 ->atPath('dureeR')
                 ->addViolation();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that errors are not display next to the field but at the top of the form.

I call my custom validator with annotation like this :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="duree_p", type="decimal", precision=3, scale=2, nullable=true)
 * @MyAssert\ExceedCharge
 */
private $dureeP;
```

The strange thing is that form some fields, it displays the error next to it, but for others it displays error at the top.

I've seen this post on StackOverflow : [Custom constraint validation error doesn't display next to field in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027491/custom-constraint-validation-error-doesnt-display-next-to-field-in-symfony2) but it didn't help me.

I tried the option "atPath()" without any success.

What I don't understand is that it works for some fields and not for the one I want...

Does anybody have any clue ?

EDIT :

I also noticed that when the violation message occurs, the field related to the violation message doesn't have any 'has-error' class and so no ".

EDIT 2 :

Here is my constraint logic :

```
    class ExceedChargeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        dump($value); //DEBUG
        dump($this->context); //DEBUG

        //get id to perform search
        $id = $this->context->getObject()->getCast()->getId();


        $consomme = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Intervention')->getConsomme($id);

        $charge = $this->context->getObject()->getCast()->getCharge();

        $prevu = $this->context->getObject()->getDureeP();
        $realise = $this->context->getObject()->getDureeR();

        dump($prevu); //DEBUG
        dump($realise); //DEBUG

        if($value != 0) {
          $total = $value + $consomme;
          if($total > $charge) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message1)
                 ->setParameter('%string%', $value)
                 ->addViolation();
            dump($this->context->getPropertyPath());
        }
        dump($this); //DEBUG    
    }

        dump($consomme);//DEBUG
        dump($charge); //DEBUG
    }
}
```

And here are some of the fiels of my Entity :

```
    /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="duree_p", type="decimal", precision=3, scale=2, nullable=true)
 * @MyAssert\ExceedCharge
 */
private $dureeP;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="duree_r", type="decimal", precision=3, scale=2, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\GreaterThan(
 *      value = 0
 *)
 */
private $dureeR;
```

The forms are generated by Easy Admin bundle

[image: Here is what I got if I attach the same constraint violation to different fields. We can see that it works fine on my "date" field but for the "dureeP" field the message is displayed at the top]

Here is what I got if I attach the same constraint violation to different fields. We can see that it works fine on my "date" field but for the "dureeP" field the message is displayed at the top

Answer (score 0):

Your `atPath` seems to be useless here, since your Constraint is a PropertyConstraint applying on string, and string do not have children.

However, when a Property Constraint raises a violation, the violation is attached to the field with the name of the property (if exists). So if your form has a `dureeP` field, the error will be attached to it, else it will be at the root of the form.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your clarification. I have indeed a field named "dureeP" and another field named "date". I f I attach the Assert on the "date" field, the violation message is displayed next to it, but if I attach the Assert on the "dureeP" field, then the violation message is displayed at the top. I don't understand why it works with some of my fields and not with the one I want :/

Comment: Could you paste more code please? (fields "date" and "dureeP" + full constraint logic would be nice)

Comment: I put you more details, tell me if it could help a bit more !

Comment: Thanks for the details. I noticed several things: You don't use $value in your Constraint, so you should actually convert your PropertyConstraint into a ClassConstraint. Attach your Constraint to your full Entity, then use `atPath` to bind the violation to the "dureeP" field. Also, I think I misunderstood your real problem: When you meant "the error is at the top", you meant the top of the field, but not the top of the full form, right?

Comment: No I meant the top of the form, sorry I forgot to be more precise. What am I suppose to do with the $value ? I noticed that when I attached my constraint on "date" field the $value give me the information of the DateTime object, but for my choice type field "dureeP" the $value returns me "0".

Comment: $value is the value of the field where the constraint is attached. In case of an EntityConstraint, this will be the full Entity. Since you don't seem to use this value directly in your validator, but you seem to check data of your full entity, I felt it would be better for your use case.

Comment: Okay I just understand how to use $value and I've modified my constraint logic, but I still have the same problem...

Comment: Have you used `atPath` to point out the good field to attach the error?

Comment: Yes, I tried something like "->atPath('dureeP')" and some other things but it didn't work. However, it's still working on some other fields but not all my fields. Some of my form fields are working (4/8), and some of them displayed the message at the top of the form.

Comment: Can you give us the code of the form for a working scenario and a non-working scenario?

Comment: I just found the answer to my problem ! I posted it below. Thank you so much for taking time to help me !

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the problem !

The problem was about my column name, including a "_" (underscore) in it.

I replaced

```
@ORM\Column(name="duree_p", type="decimal", precision=3, scale=2)
```

By

```
@ORM\Column(name="prevu", type="decimal", precision=3, scale=2)
```

And it solved the problem. So no underscore in the name and we're done !

How did I found it ?
By creating a dummy (basic) validator test and attaching it to some fields of another of my entities. I saw it was working on all fields so I compared the difference between the two entity and it was the only difference.

Here is the validator I use to troubleshoot :

```
class TestValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {

        dump($value);

        if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('%string%', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }

    }
}
```